# Obfuscate Resources files in Android App Bundle?

Tags: obfuscation

How can I obfuscate the resources files (drawables, layout, etc.) in AAB format?
the resources files are only obfuscated for me when generating an APK File using `minifyEnabled = true` in `build.gradle` file, but not when generating an App Bundle.

Comment: I've noticed the same behaviour. Did you find any answers yet?